# Non-ascii characters not getting filtered through regex in java

Tags: regex, non-ascii-characters

I am using regex [^\x00-\x7F] to filter any non- ascii characters in my Java application. It is filtering most of the characters but recently found a problem where it is letting the control character called 'Start of Guarded area', see link (https://www.codetable.net/name/start-of-guarded-area) to pass through and appear as – in my xml files. Though this character is a non-ascii i.e. out of (0-127) range, Can anybody throw some light why is it not being filtered and if there are any other characters which might not get filtered like this. Note that I am using xstream parser for parsing the text. Any suggestions would be well appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Just use `s = s.replaceAll("\\P{ASCII}+", "")` to remove all non-ASCII symbols. If there are issues like some Unicode symbols get corrupt, it is not the regex issue, check the encodings.

Comment: Can you give a [mcve]?

Comment: We are using an xstream parser which is converting the actual 'start of guard character' to its hex value &#x96; and appending to my xmls. I tried solution by Wiktor but character is still not removed. I still can't figure out why the regex [^\x00-\x7F] is not filtering this character when it is filtering all other such characters which are non-ascii. Does somebody know what's the default encoding for xstream parser.